# why tensorflow word2vec_optimized lower than c word2vec (2X+)

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

i find c code is 2X quicker than tensorflow version.

`word2vec -train train.zh -output vec.txt -size 200 -window 5 -negative 5 -hs 0 -binary 0 -cbow 0`

i get `Words/thread/sec: 53.95k`

`python word2vec_optimized.py --train_data=train.zh --save_path=./tmp --eval_data=analogy.txt --num_neg_samples 5`

i get `words/sec =    257411`

the c code , all perfamance is 54k*12=600k+, when tensorflow 250k.

any detail i miss, or anyone can simply explain why is this?
Thansk~